# Perl CGI does not update session variables during If-Else / While

Tags: ajax, perl, session, cgi

The code below has an AJAX call that starts an if statement and counts up from the last stored session param + 10.

Another AJAX call immediately begins to poll the form.cgi for the current session param.

I expect the session param to be updated about once per second as per the time condition, and thus I should get a stream of numbers incremental one at a time. (The polling code is also being run in one second increments).

This is what I expect from the Console of the web browser, each one second apart:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...(press submit again)...12,13,14,15...etc..
```

The issue is that the value that comes back from the polling AJAX call only updates once per while loop (each ten seconds)

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,10,10, (press submit again)...10,10,10,10,10...
```

It seems that the session variable is only being committed to server storage when the If and While are complete.

Is there a way around this? I plan to run many system scripts with an If statement and would like to be able to poll the form.cgi for updates instead of having to wait until all of the operations are complete.

**form.cgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser'; # sends error messages to the browser!
use CGI::Session;
use JSON;

my $workTimer = 1; # In milliseconds.

my $query = CGI->new();
my $session = CGI::Session->new($query);
print $session->header();

if(defined $query->param('name')){

    my $sec = time();
    my $count = $session->param('script1');
    my $max = $count + 10;

    while($count < $max){
        if(time() > $sec + $workTimer){
            $count = $session->param('script1');
            $count = $count + 1;
            $session->param('script1', $count);
            $sec = time();
        }
    }

    print "While finished.";
}
elsif(defined $query->param('polling')){
    my @pollingArray = ();

    push(@pollingArray, $session->param('script1'));

    my $json->{"poll-reply"} = \@pollingArray;
    my $json_text = to_json($json);

    print "$json_text";
}
else{
    print <<"EOF";
<html><head>
        <script src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js" defer></script>
        <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head><body>
EOF

    # Print the form area.
    print <<"EOF";
    <form id="test-form">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
EOF

    # Print the bottom of the HTML page.
    print <<"EOF";
    </body>
</html>
EOF

}
```

**app.js**

```
$('#submit').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/form/form.cgi",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            name: "-"
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    var polling = pollingForStatus();
});

function pollingForStatus(){
    return window.setInterval(function(){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "/form/form.cgi",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                polling: "poll"
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        }); 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Don't have time to read this in detail, but it sounds like you need to add `$session->flush()` to the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling flush() after making updates to the session that you want to be visible outside the current request.

See https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#flush